# Is the same variable used to keep track of comment up-votes on Meta and SO?

Tags: discussion, support, stack-overflow, comment-voting

As in, if I run out of comment up-votes, *CUVs*, on meta, will I also run out of CUVs on SO?  I don't see why this would be the case, as question/answer vote counts are not shared between Meta and SO; **however**, I've run out of CUVs on Meta twice, and both times I also ran out of CUVs on SO.

Not sure if this is by *coincidence*, a *bug* or *intended behavior*.  Anyone have any insight?

Comment: Hard to believe it's the same counter, those are two independent sites by all means.

Comment: That's what I figured, too, and I know that my sample size is small, but nonetheless, what are the odds that both times I run out of CUVs on Meta, that I also ran out of CUVs on SO, but didn't know because I didn't attempt to upvote an additional comment?  It's probably a coincidence, but at the moment, I don't have a way to test it.

Comment: Im 99% sure ive run out of comment votes on meta (which I do often) and not run out on SO

Comment: easy way to test it; use up all your votes on one site or the other on my comments ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yep, this is by coincidence. They’re not the same counter. I’ve run out of votes on each one at different times plenty before.